# Custom sort of nested document

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have a collection `fruits {name:'orange', id:1}....` and another one `users`, `user`s have document `favorites: [1,2,3]`. I want to display the `favourite` fruits at first and then the rest.

I can query twice like first with `fruits.find({id: {$id:[user.favorites]}})` and then with `not in` and then merge them.

Is there any other way to do it? Is there a possibility to pass custom function to `sort`, if so. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Meteor doesn't allow a custom sort function. What you can do, is use the [`sortBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) and [`contains()`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) functions from the [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/) library to sort your items:

```js
var fruitsSorted = _.sortBy(fruits.find(selector).fetch(), (fruit) => {
    if(_.contains(user.favorites, fruit.id)){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
});
```

You now have a sorted array in `fruitsSorted`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have queried `fruits` collection for all fruits.

```
var fruits = [
    { name: 'orange', id: 1},
    { name: 'apple', id: 2},
    { name: 'banana', id: 3}
];
```

Now you can use [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) and [`includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) function from [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs) library to sort the fruits as per user favourites.

```
var sortedFruits = _.sortBy(fruits, function(fruit) {
    return _.includes(user.favourites, fruit.id) ? 0 : 1;
});
```